# getElementById in a For loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, getelementbyid

I'm using a For loop to run through an array and return relevant strings. When I use getElementById, I only get the last string, but if I use document.write, everything comes out fine.

```
var names = ["John","Jamie","Jessica","Judy","Jeffery","Joy"];
for (i=0,tot=names.length; i < tot; i++) {
 document.getElementById("namelist").innerHTML = names[i];
}
```

and the HTML is
    `<p id="namelist">list of names go here</p>`

What I get when I run that is "Joy". Is it not possible to use getElementById in this case? Is there some other way to get the returned list inside of one element?

I've read through some of the other questions and answers on here, but none are exactly what I want

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want all those strings in `document.getElementById("namelist").innerHTML` ?

Comment: Of course you only get the last, since every `innerHTML` replaces the entire inner HTML.

Comment: document.getElementById("namelist").innerHTML = names[i];
am confused r u trying to assign to namelist or trying to retrieve it from namelist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting a value in a loop.

First you set it to John. Then you set it to Jamie (so it is no longer John) and so on.

If you want to append a value then you need to do something like:

```
document.getElementById("namelist").innerHTML = document.getElementById("namelist").innerHTML + names[i];
```

(Using the `+=` operator would be shorter)

If you just want to drop the whole lot in, then there is no need to use a loop:

```
document.getElementById("namelist").innerHTML = names.join(' ');
```

Comment: which could be written as `document.getElementById("namelist").innerHTML += names[i] + "<br/>";`

Comment: @mplungjan — I did mention that. I went with the long version so what was happening was explicit and didn't need knowledge of the shortcut operator.

Comment: So show how to use the showrtcut operator as you call it. For me it is the only operator to use when appending.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for! I didn't know it was possible to add it together like that.
and I need the loop because it's not always i=0; I just set it at that for the example

Answer (score 0):

```
var names = ["John","Jamie","Jessica","Judy","Jeffery","Joy"];
for (i=0,tot=names.length; i < tot; i++) {
 document.getElementById("namelist").innerHTML += names[i];
}
```

+= instead of =

Answer (score 0):

if you want to print all names then you need to append all names in element's innerHTML.

```
var names = ["John","Jamie","Jessica","Judy","Jeffery","Joy"];
for (i=0,tot=names.length; i < tot; i++) {
 document.getElementById("namelist").innerHTML += names[i]+"<br/>" ;
}
```

Comment: yes use of += will be nice . i have edited my answer as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("namelist").innerHTML += names[i] + "<br/>"
```

is likely what you want

the operator I use is `+=` where

```
a += b;
```

is the same as

```
a = a + b;
```

A simpler way is

```
var names = ["John","Jamie","Jessica","Judy","Jeffery","Joy"];
document.getElementById("namelist").innerHTML = names[i].join(", ");
```

Comment: thanks, i didn't use .join() because I don't always need the entire list, but += is perfect

Answer (score 0):

a quick write up replace = with +=

```
var names = ["John","Jamie","Jessica","Judy","Jeffery","Joy"];
for (i=0,tot=names.length; i < tot; i++) {
 document.getElementById("namelist").innerHTML += names[i];
}
```